# Get Sum of Count of Objects

Tags: c#, lambda, sum

I have a Lambda expression like so:

```
model =
    db.MyTable.Where(
            x => x.deleted == false && x.MyDate.Month == monthInt && x.MyDate.Year == yearInt)
        .GroupBy(x => x.codeAC.ACatagory.Text)
        .Select(y => new MainAssignmentReportVM()
        {
            Title = y.Key,
            Children = y.Select(z => new AssignmentReportVM()
            {
                Assignment = z.codeAC.text,
                Location = z.codeLocation.Location,
                Count =
                    y.Count(
                        t =>
                            t.codeAC.text == z.codeAC.text &&
                            t.codeLocation.Location == z.codeLocation.Location),
                EachFlightTotal = y.Where(s => s.codeAC.text == z.codeAC.text && s.codeLocation.Location == z.codeLocation.Location).Sum(s => s.Flight.Value),
                TotalFlightCombined = y.Sum(x => x.Flight.Value),
                // AssignmentTotalCount -- This is where I need help
            }).Distinct()
        });
```

I have commented my code above on where I need assistance.  `AssignmentTotalCount` should be the Sum of `Count`.  How do I make that happen in this lambda expression?

I was thinking making `AssignmentTotalCount` a readonly property and set it in the class since it will not be edited, or anything.. but I don't know how to set that up in the class.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you place `AssignmentTotalCount` where you put it, then taking the 'sum' of `Count` will always be the same as `Count`. I'd say it has to be placed one level higher, as a sibling of `Title` and `Children` - could that be correct?

Comment: Uhm, why do you need `AssignmentTotalCount` to be *inside* of each model ? Is it a static number or should it be different for each element of collection ?

Comment: @PeterB Trying that now.

Comment: @PeterB That worked!  I did this in the `MainAssignmentReportVM` class.  `public int AssignmentTotalCount => Children.Sum(x => x.Count);`.  That did it!  Make it an answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing `AssignmentTotalCount` where you put it, taking the Sum of `Count` will always be the same as Count.

It has to be placed one level higher, as a sibling of `Title` and `Children` (so a property of class `MainAssignmentReportVM` instead of class `AssignmentReportVM`). Then you should be able to sum over `Count`.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting outside the linq expression a

```
int sumCount = 0;
```

and do after

```
Count = y.Count(.....
```

this

```
sumCount += Count;``
```